# Is biblatex sorting option sortcase sorting sensitively or case insensitively by default?

Tags: biblatex

This is what the `biblatex` documentation says on the `sortcase` option:
 [image: [sortcase=true, false] Whether or not to sort the bibliography and the list of shorthands case-sensitively. default: true]

I am not a native English speaker. Therefore, after reading that, I am not really sure whether `sortcase=true` means it will eventually sort case sensitively or case insensitively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

> [sortcase] Whether or not to sort the bibliography and the list of shorthands case-sensitively.

`sortcase=true` means that sorting is case sensitive. `sortcase=false` means sorting is case insensitive. This may become slightly clearer from the Biber documentation, which has

> Collation is by default case sensitive. You can turn this off globally using the Biber option `--sortcase=false` or from Biblatex using its option `sortcase=false`.
>   [...]
>   By default, Biber collates uppercase before lower. You can reverse this globally for
>   all sorting using the Biber option `--sortupper=false` or from
>   Biblatex by using its option `sortupper=false`.

You can experiment with that in

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authortitle, sortcase=true, sortupper=true, backend=biber]{biblatex}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{appleby:ua,
  author  = {Humphrey Appleby},
  title   = {A},
  date    = {1982},
}
@book{appleby:la,
  author  = {Humphrey Appleby},
  title   = {a},
  date    = {1985},
}
@book{appleby:ub,
  author  = {Humphrey Appleby},
  title   = {B},
  date    = {1984},
}
@book{appleby:lb,
  author  = {Humphrey Appleby},
  title   = {b},
  date    = {1983},
}
@book{bppleby:ua,
  author  = {Humphrey Bppleby},
  title   = {AK},
  date    = {1982},
}
@book{bppleby:la,
  author  = {Humphrey Bppleby},
  title   = {al},
  date    = {1985},
}
@book{bppleby:ub,
  author  = {Humphrey Bppleby},
  title   = {BL},
  date    = {1984},
}
@book{bppleby:lb,
  author  = {Humphrey Bppleby},
  title   = {bk},
  date    = {1983},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}
\begin{document}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

### `sortcase=true`

[image: A (1982) < a (1985) < B (1984) < b (1983)]

### `sortcase=false`

[image: A (1982) < a (1985) < b (1983) < B (1984)]

This example also shows that case sensitive sorting only becomes important if there is a tie when we only look at the letters.

- "ak"/"AK" always sorts before "al"/"AL", no matter what capitalisation the two letters use.
- But "A" only sorts before "a" with `sortcase=true` (and `sortupper=true`).

If I understand correctly this behaviour is consistent with the Unicode Collation Algorithm: https://unicode.org/reports/tr10/.